# Cannot call another class

Tags: java, class, compilation, call

I'm making a Java program that can solve the roots using the quadratic equation by giving a, b, and c.

Here is the main code:

```
//main file

class Call
{
       public static void main(String args [])
    {
            double a=Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
            double b=Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
            double c=Double.parseDouble(args[3]);

            Receiver r = new Receiver(".");
            if (r.determine(a,b,c)=true)
            {
                    double root1=r.Root;
                    double root2=r.Root2;
                    System.out.println("The first root is +root1");
                    System.out.println("The second root is +root2");


            }
            else
            {
                    System.out.println("Not a number");
            }
    }
 }
```

Now here's the class I'm trying to call but couldn't.

```
   class Receiver
    {
    public boolean determine(double a, double b, double c)
    {
            double value=b*b-4*a*c;
                    if (value<0)
                            return false;
                    else
                            return true;
    }

    public double Root(double a, double b, double c)
    {
            double value=b*b-4*a*c;
            double root=(-b+ Math.sqrt(value))/(2*a);
            return root;
    }

    public double Root2(double a, double b, double c)
    {
            double value=b*b-4*a*c;
            double root2=(-b- Math.sqrt(value))/(2*a);
            return root2;
    }
    }
```

I made sure that I compiled the Receiver.java already. But when I compile Call.java, I get this error:

```
Call.java:14:error:cannot find symbol
      Receiver r= new Receiver();
      symbol: class Receiver
      location: class Call
```

Comment: have a look as `package` and `import` keyword in java.

Comment: are you useing any `IDE` ? Like **Eclipse** or **NetBeans** ?

Comment: This does look like an import problem, although it's impossible to tell for sure without more information.  But I would point out that the lines `double root1=r.Root;` and `double root2=r.Root2;` won't compile even if this particular compilation error is fixed.  You'll have to call `Root` and `Root2` with actual arguments.

Comment: and where is that constructor defined? (".")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note that I haven't found constructor `public Receiver(String arg)`, and you're using it like this, aren't you missing that?**

If you're compiling those by yourself from **command line** ensure, these steps:

**Create package with those class**

```
// top of Call.java
package com.mypackage.app;

// top of Receiver.java
package com.mypackage.app;
```

**Compile those files so that package is created in class structure**
(this will create folders in current location like `/com/mypackage/app/`)

```
javac -d . Call.java Receiver.java
```

**Run the Call class from current location by it's package name**

```
java com.mypackage.app.Call
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `Receiver`s constructor with a String parameter, but in you the code for `Receiver` you posted there is no such constructor.

Also, you could try making the class `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile both files at the same time, or insure that the compiler has been passed a reference to the Receiver class file. Also, the constructor in the Receiver does not take a string parameter.

Generally it is considered good practice to put source files in packages (directories) - it makes it easier to organise them as your projects get bigger. For example in your case you may choose a package name like "com.myapp.roots", and put both your source files in a directory like "myFirstProject/src/com/myapp/roots". Then from the "myFirstProject" directory you should be able to call "javac src" to compile everything in the source directory

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html